# Version name being rejected in Google App Engine

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy version `0-8-1-SNAPSHOT` of my Java application to Google App Engine. I get the following error:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=versature-dashboardhr&version=0-8-1-SNAPSHOT&
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Unable to assign value '0-8-1-SNAPSHOT' to attribute 'version':
Value '0-8-1-SNAPSHOT' for version does not match expression '^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{1,100}$'
```

I believe `0-8-1-SNAPSHOT` matches regex `^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{1,100}$`…

I am using the Maven plugin to deploy, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you to @Lipis for catching my glaring oversight! I should add that I used the GMaven plugin to convert the `project.version` property to lowercase before filtering `appengine-web.xml`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get rid of the CAPITAL letters and you'll be fine. It doesn't match the regular expression otherwise.